# How to "filter" maps properly in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I ve been playing around w/ Clojure for a while and I got stuck in something I think very trivial for many...but not me. I've the following piece of code;

```
;; Define a Record structure
(defrecord Person [first-name last-name age occupation])

(def john (->Person "John" "Frusciante" 50 "Guitarist"))

;; People map
(def people {"1" john
             "2" (->Person "Pablo" "Neruda" 90 "Poet")
             "3" (->Person "Stefan" "Zweig" 120 "Author")
             }
) 

(defn get-120-year-old-guy
  [peeps]
  (filter #(= (:age %) 120) peeps)
)

(println "who's 120?: " (get-120-year-old-guy people))
```

This call returns an empty list. I know it's something wrong the way I retrieve the value but can't see what is that exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a hint of what's going on by changing the function temporarily:

```
(defn get-120-year-old-guy
  [peeps]
  (filter (fn [m] (println (type m) m)) peeps))
```

Prints:

```
(clojure.lang.MapEntry [1 #user.Person{:first-name John, :last-name Frusciante, :age 50, :occupation Guitarist}]
clojure.lang.MapEntry [2 #user.Person{:first-name Pablo, :last-name Neruda, :age 90, :occupation Poet}]
clojure.lang.MapEntry [3 #user.Person{:first-name Stefan, :last-name Zweig, :age 120, :occupation Author}]
)
```

Note how each entry is a `MapEntry`. In your attempt, you're applying `:age` to the whole `MapEntry` (which returns `nil`), not just the person.

I think destructuring using a full anonymous function would be the easiest way:

```
(defn get-120-year-old-guy
  [peeps]
  (filter (fn [[_ person]] (= (:age person) 120)) peeps))
```

Outputs:

```
who's 120?:  ([3 #user.Person{:first-name Stefan, :last-name Zweig, :age 120, :occupation Author}])
```

---

@leetwinski points out a more idiomatic solution that does away with the explicit function altogether:

```
(filter (comp #{120} :age val) people)
```

Broken down:

```
(defn get-120-year-old-guy [peeps]
  (filter (comp  ; And (comp)ose all three checks together
             #{120}  ; Then test if it's in the set of #{120}
             :age  ; Then get the age
             val)  ; Get the value from the MapEntry
           peeps))
```

Comment: or just `(filter (comp #{120} :age val) people)`

Comment: @leetwinski Ya, that's true. To be honest, I haven't written Clojure for like two years now. I'm super rusty.

Comment: wow. @Carcigenicate what have you switched to? if it isn't a secret )

Comment: @leetwinski I'm in school for Information Security, so I've switched to Python, C, and assembly for the sake of the course. I tell you, it's hard going from a fluent, succinct language like Clojure to C.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the first item in your outer map, you'll see that each item is a `clojure.lang.MapEntry` from string to Person. The key is "1" and the value is a Person record:

```
> (first people)
["1"
 {:first-name "John",
  :last-name "Frusciante",
  :age 50,
  :occupation "Guitarist"}]
```

To filter on the :age field, you have to first get the value of the {key, value} pair. One way is to use the val function to get that before getting :age from the Person map. Your filter function is then:

```
(defn get-120-year-old-guy
  [peeps]
  (filter #(= (:age (val %)) 120) peeps)
)

> (println "who's 120?: " (get-120-year-old-guy people))
who's 120?:  ([3 #challenges.anag.Person{:first-name Stefan, :last-name Zweig, :age 120, :occupation Author}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [destructure](https://blog.brunobonacci.com/2014/11/16/clojure-complete-guide-to-destructuring/) the `clojure.lang.MapEntry`:

```
(defn get-120-year-old-guy
  [peeps]
  (filter (fn [[_ v]] (= (:age v) 120)) peeps)
)
```

Here you can see `(fn [[_ v]] ...` where the `_` is used as a place holder for the unused `key`.